# Get all results ids before paginate in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination

Here is my code:

```php
$prestations = Prestation::with([
        'service' => function($query) {
            $query->select(['id','name']);
        },
        'facility' => function($query) {
            $query->select(['id','name']);
        },
        'conciergeries.network' => function($query) {
            $query->select(['id','name']);
        }
    ])
    ->whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($sService) {
        $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$sService/i");
    })
    ->whereHas('facility', function ($query) use ($sPartner) {
        $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$sPartner/i");
    })
    ->whereHas('conciergeries.network', function ($query) use ($sSubsidiary) {
        $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$sSubsidiary/i");
    })
    ->options([
        'collation' => [
            'locale' => 'en_US',
            'strength' => 1
        ]
    ])
    ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
    ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
    ->paginate(25);
```

When i tried to get all ids :

```php
$arrIds = [];

foreach ($prestations as $prestation) {
    array_push($arrIds, $prestation->_id);
}
```

The problem is that I get only ids of 25 elements of my pagination.
How to get ids of all results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hold your query on a `$prestationsQuery` variable and call it 2 times like this:

```php
$prestationsQuery = Prestation::with([
        'service:id,name',
        'facility:id,name',
        'conciergeries.network' => function($query) {
            $query->select(['id','name']);
        }
    ])
    ->whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($sService) {
        $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$sService/i");
    })
    ->whereHas('facility', function ($query) use ($sPartner) {
        $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$sPartner/i");
    })
    ->whereHas('conciergeries.network', function ($query) use ($sSubsidiary) {
        $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$sSubsidiary/i");
    })
    ->options([
        'collation' => [
            'locale' => 'en_US',
            'strength' => 1
        ]
    ])
    ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
    ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection);

$arrIds = $prestationsQuery->pluck('_id');

$prestations = $prestationsQuery->paginate(25);
```

Remember to call `paginate` after `pluck`.

Another way is to use `tap` function like this:

```php
$arrIds = [];

$prestations = Prestation::with([
        'service:id,name',
        'facility:id,name',
        'conciergeries.network' => function($query) {
            $query->select(['id','name']);
        }
    ])
    ->whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($sService) {
        $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$sService/i");
    })
    ->whereHas('facility', function ($query) use ($sPartner) {
        $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$sPartner/i");
    })
    ->whereHas('conciergeries.network', function ($query) use ($sSubsidiary) {
        $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$sSubsidiary/i");
    })
    ->options([
        'collation' => [
            'locale' => 'en_US',
            'strength' => 1
        ]
    ])
    ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
    ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection);
    ->tap(function ($query) use (&$arrIds) {
        $arrIds = $query->pluck('_id');
    })
    ->paginate(25);
```